# Where is the home URL set in Wordpress?

Tags: home-url

We're using the Alone theme in Wordpress 4.9.9.  When I go to the settings page, it lists the home URL as http://sitename  and the site URL as https://sitename.  Where in Wordpress is the home URL set? I need it to be https://sitename.

Answer (score 1):

Go to Admin > Settings > General - paste https://sitename in both the WordPress Address (URL) and Site Address (URL) fields.

[image]

---

You can also edit these values in wp-config.php by adding the following.

```
define( 'WP_HOME', 'http://example.com' );
define( 'WP_SITEURL', 'http://example.com' );
```

---

Or edit the values directly in the database by editing the wp_options table and editing the values of "siteurl" and "home".

---

Here is more info on [changing the site URL](https://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_The_Site_URL).

Comment: Thanks, RiddleMeThis. That's what I expected, but when I go to my settings/general page the Wordpress Address and Site Address fields are not there.

Comment: I've updated my answer to include more places to look and things to try :)